# Pandas dataframe, how to access column name in UTF8

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unicode

I have an ANSI encoded CSV file like below. I can import it as a dataframe with `df = pd.read_csv(ans, encoding='ansi', skipinitialspace=True)` and then access any column with `df['aÌ…']` etc.

The ANSI encoding is hard to read and I would rather use UTF8. But I don't know how to access columns by name with UTF8. For example, for `df['aÌ…']` as UTF8, I tried various versions of the following that all returned KeyErrors on the column name (I also tried different bar encodings, this is just one example for brevity):

```
bar = u'\u0305'
df[bar + 'a']
```

Is there a way I can print the column names like `df.columns` where it will show me the encoding, then I will know how to define variables like `bar` and epsilon, etc.?

**Problem Statement**

file.csv, ANSI encoding:

```
     a,      aÌ…,    b,    bÌ…,     ÎµÌ…,    Î£Îµ,    Îµ0
5,7.69,5.25,5.28,2.39,3.33,0
5,7.87,5.75,5.73,2.05,3.85,0
```

Hard to read and I have to remember `df['aÌ…']` is a_bar, etc.:

[image]

Easy to read, but how do I access the columns by name?

[image]

Comment: try getting the columns names from `df.columns`

Comment: "I have an ANSI encoded CSV file".  No, you have a UTF-8-encoded file that you are reading incorrectly.  But you can read the file as UTF-8, then get the columns names as show above and assign them to other variables, like `a,b,c,d,e,f,g = df.columns`, then for example `df[g]` will work (pick meaningful names ).  Those names are actually valid identifiers, so if you use an IDE with tab-completion you can type `df.Σε` in source and it will work.

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch yes, that was what I wanted to do. This returns ```Index(['a', 'a̅', 'b', 'b̅', 'ε̅', 'Σε', 'ε0'], dtype='object')```. Of course I can copy/paste to do ```df['a̅']```, but I don't want to have to copy/paste a character like ```a̅```

Comment: @MarkTolonen agreed that is the right approach, but the column order and number of columns can vary. Tab completion doesn't seem to work for this in Jupyter Notebooks?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the columns by location rather than name.

https://pythonhow.com/python-tutorial/pandas/Accessing-pandas-dataframe-columns-rows-and-cells/

In the tutorial, it explains accessing the information in a bit more details but a general example is...

```
df2.loc["California", : ] #extracts a row from the frame by name

df2.iloc[0:3,0:4] # extracts based on position based indexing.
```

I would review the tutorial and the panda documentation and play around with it.

Comment: How would this work if the column order varies?

Comment: It won't. you should rethink what you're doing if the column names aren't accessible via name and the location changes.  I would suggest maybe running the columns you can't name through a dictionary with a key numbered value and then naming the columns from the key values.